# What is the maximum possible averge power of the geomagnetic electric generator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, power, geomagnetism

Earth's magnetic field strength varies from 25 to 65 μT on the surface. Therefore, magnetic energy is approximately $V\frac{1}{2} \frac{B^2}{\mu\mu_0} \approx  10^{\left (17,5\cdots 18,5  \right )} \text{ J}$ . [Total variations of the Earths magnetic field are percentages per day.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227326920_Observing_Modeling_and_Interpreting_Magnetic_Fields_of_the_Solid_Earth)
So averge power is $$\frac{10^{\left (17,5\cdots 18,5  \right )} \text{ J } \cdot \left (1\cdots 10  \right ) \text{%}}{1 \text{ day}} \approx  \left (3\cdots 300  \right ) \text{ GW}$$ It is only need a coil around the equator for production of electric power.

[image]

Comment: You would not get power from the static magnetic field of Earth.  You only get it from induction, i.e., dB/dt.  The magnitude of the magnetic field variations are much much smaller than Earth's dipole field...